# Arrow for top of page

Tags: javascript, css

I have this funciton for my arrow:

```
<script>
        $(window).scroll(function() {
    var pxFromBottom = 1300;
    if ($(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height() > $(document).height() - pxFromBottom) {
        $('#nagore').fadeIn('slow');
    } else {
        $('#nagore').fadeOut('slow')
        }
    }); 
</script>
```

I want to change this var from Bottom top Top.

so instead of

```
pxFromBottom = 1300
```

to become

```
pxFromTop = 1300
```

but the problem is that it is not working when I change it to TOP. How can I do this?

Comment: are you changing in if condition too, right?

Comment: can you upload your html and css code also or working demo

Comment: I am feeling so so so stupid Dilip :D. The dumbest question I have ever asked.

Comment: Haha!! :D.. It happens sometimes!!

Answer (score 0):

`$(document).height() - pxFromBottom` will give you the relative position from top of the page. That is the same as `pxFromTop` value itself, so replacing that should work:

```
$(window).scroll(function() {
    var pxFromTop = 1300;
    if ($(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height() > pxFromTop) {
        $('#nagore').fadeIn('slow');
    } else {
        $('#nagore').fadeOut('slow')
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this may help.

```
$(document).scroll(function() {
var pxFromTop = $(this).scrollTop();
 if (pxFromTop > 1300) {
   $('#nagore').fadeIn('slow');
   } else {
     $('#nagore').fadeOut('slow');
   }
});
```

**[See the working example](https://jsfiddle.net/demaxglobal/u1e7cntu/)**

```
 .container{
  width: 100%;
  height: 2600px;
 }

#nagore{
 display: none;
 background: #222;
 width: 50px; 
 height: 50px;
 position: fixed;
 bottom: 10px;
 right: 10px;
 border-radius: 50px;
}
```